# converting a contourf() plot with grid on with matlab2tikz script

Tags: matlab, latex, tikz, contourf

When I convert a `counterf()` plot with matlab2tikz it won't show me the grid. Even though I have set the grid on. In the MATLAB plot I can see the grid, but in the compiled Latex pdf I can't see it.

My MATLAB code:

```
contourf(v);
colorbar;
title('el. Potential V(x,y)');
grid on;
xlabel('x-Achse');
ylabel('y-Achse');
matlab2tikz('pic1.tikz');
```

in the MATLAB plot I see this:
[image: matlab plot]

and in the compiled LaTeX PDF I see this:
[image: tikz picture]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You can upload the picture to any image hoster (or dropbox, ...) and put a link to your image in your question (edit question for that). Then somebody with more reputation can insert the image for you.

Comment: Put the link to the pictures and we will add them. Do you need the iage in tikz? There is a very nice FEX submission called `export_fig`, it is the best thing there is to save Matlab figures. Try it.

Comment: thx for the help, i add a screenshot of the Latex pdf...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment (Apr. 2015), this behavior is not a feature in matlab2tikz yet. According to [this bug report](https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz/issues/569), it is known to the developers and as it seems they plan on adding this feature / removing this bug in the near future.

So as for now, you can either wait for the addition of this feature to matlab2tikz, add it to matlab2tikz yourself and create a pull-request on Github, or manually add the grid to the generated TikZ file.

Comment: You could create a very simple example (e.g. plot a line + create grid), run it through `matlab2tikz` and ask a question on [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) how to add a grid to that plot.

Comment: Just a minor correction: it is not a bug but a feature request. Also, any user can submit a Pull Request to the develop branch of https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz and we (matlab2tikz team) will be happy to review it

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly @OlegKomarov. Sorry if it sounded a bit harsh before.

Comment: No problems. Just wanted to say we are aware of the missing feature and any help is welcome :)